# fake/mock nonvirtual C++ methods without changing the production code on Visual Studio platform

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I am unit testing a c++ class and using Google Test and Google Mock frameworks.

For example,
I have a class which has non-virtual functions and I want to mock these two functions which have external dependencies.
I don't want to change my class `A` (using gmock template way solution and dependency injection). Below can be two solutions probably:

1. Simply mock on fly or any other option like we have in Python where we create `MagicMock()` and patch.
2. derive non-virtual class from the test class and wrap the non-virtual
   function by making it virtual in the test class, then call the prod non-virtual function.

```cpp
class A 
{
  public:
          bool DBConnect(string username);
  private:
          bool someWork(int);
};
```

Comment: Didin't try but I read somewhere this is good [FSeam](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/07/02/fseam-a-mocking-framework-that-requires-no-change-in-code-part-1/).

Comment: [FSeam part 2](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/07/05/fseam-a-mocking-framework-that-requires-no-change-in-code-part-2/).

Comment: Anyone can please provide some inputs here, Eagerly waiting?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You have to make your C++ code *testable*.

Solutions that work in interpreted languages, such as Python, are not generally suitable for C++. This is mainly because C++ is compiled and lacks native support for reflection.

There may, however, be a solution for your *external depedencies*. If those are provided through a library, you can use [library preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) to use a different implementation for your unit tests.